# Variable cannot be resolved after adding input validation

Tags: android, validation, if-statement

I added a simple if statement to check if the user entered value is greater than zero around the code where I set the editText input to a variable.

But after adding the if clauses the below variables I get this error: `getoffsetlength cannot be resolved to a variable`

This is how I implemented the input validation below.Can anyone advice me as to what I'm doing wrong with this implementation? What I'm thinking is that the variables `getoffsetLength` etc.. have become out of range after adding the if clauses.But how would I fix this?

```
if (offsetLength.getText().length() > 0 ) {
            String getoffsetlength = offsetLength.getText().toString(); 
            }

            if (offsetDepth.getText().length() > 0 ) {
            String getoffsetdepth = offsetDepth.getText().toString(); 
            }
            if (ductDepth.getText().length() > 0 ) {
            String getductdepth = ductDepth.getText().toString(); 
            }
            double tri1,tri2;
            //double marking1,marking2,marking3;

            //error here on all three variables
            double off1 = Double.parseDouble(getoffsetlength);
            double off2 = Double.parseDouble(getoffsetdepth);
            double off3 = Double.parseDouble(getductdepth);
```

Comment: declare it as a class member

Comment: Can you explain further please?

Comment: declare `String getoffsetlength` as a class member before `onCreate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to initialize the variables `getoffsetlength,getoffsetdepth,getductdepth`

```
String getoffsetlength,getoffsetdepth,getductdepth  = null;
if (offsetLength.getText().length() > 0 ) {
   getoffsetlength = offsetLength.getText().toString(); 
}

if (offsetDepth.getText().length() > 0 ) {
    getoffsetdepth = offsetDepth.getText().toString(); 
}
if (ductDepth.getText().length() > 0 ) {
    getductdepth = ductDepth.getText().toString(); 
}
double tri1,tri2;
//double marking1,marking2,marking3;

// validate whether the variables are not null
if(getoffsetlength != null){
    double off1 = Double.parseDouble(getoffsetlength);
}
if(getoffsetdepth != null){
    double off2 = Double.parseDouble(getoffsetdepth);
}
if(getductdepth != null){
double off3 = Double.parseDouble(getductdepth);
}
```

Comment: Will this be sufficient to prevent the app from crashing if a null value is entered?I tried the above using just the check for zero but it crashed.